# Hindsight is 20/20

Tags: idioms

I know that this phrase is used to describe the fact that it is easy for one to be knowledgable about an event after it has happened. That is, an individual has a realization about the event that should have been obvious all along, yet they didn't catch on because they were acting in the heat of the moment (according to Urban Dictionary).

What is the origin of the phrase? Why 20/20? Is it related to denoting vision of normal sharpness (twenty-twenty)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisely.  The proverb uses 20/20 to evoke eyesight. Hindsight is the only kind of "sight" that is perfect.